# If cell contains X and date in cell Y is older than 1 month then hide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone take a look at this and help me figure out why its not working as intended?

If column N is ticked (✔) it should add the date (this is working).
I then want it to auto hide the rows that have the tick and the date is older than one month. But its hiding non-ticked rows.

This is what I have so far:

```
function hideRows() {
  //Logger.log(v.length);

  var values = range.getValues();
  var v = s.getRange('P5:P').getValues().join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
  var today = new Date().getTime();
  var oneMonth = 2629746000;
  for (var i=15;i<v.length;i++) {
    // Date Object from cell in B2:B in milliseconds 
  var vDate = new Date(v[i]).getTime(); 
    if (today - vDate <= oneMonth && (values[i][0] === "✔")) {
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(i+1);
  s.hideRows(5, i);
}
```

Comment: The code has a comment "Date Object from cell in B2:B in milliseconds " but you get your date from column P. Just checking if that is from an older version of the code or a bug?

Comment: Good spot! I uploaded the wrong version of the code! I will amend my post above.